# Don't elipsify answer bodies in search if it's not required

Tags: bug, answers, search

I use search quite often, and sometimes come across gems like this:

[image]

I'd like to know whether that's actually all that's there... and that `...` makes me hesitate. On one hand, maybe there's code there or something that makes it a not-NAA. On the other, maybe it's this:

[image]

This has been bugging me for months, I just haven't bothered to write it up before. So, fix please?

Comment: What search is this? [Can't reproduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nvXsb.png) and what is the "NAA" between the score and the "votes"??

Comment: @ShadowWizard [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22answer+at%22+url%3A%22*%22+is%3Aa+score%3A..0) and userscript.

Comment: So advanced search only. Cool userscript! :)

Comment: Bountied, @ShadowWizard. Shame I'm too lazy to look up how to spell 'ellipses', otherwise I would have found that :P

Comment: lol, had to Google to find correct syntax but yeah, many times we're sure nobody found the bug.